# Word, idiom or expression to describe feeling full (after eating)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, expressions, idiom-requests

For example:

> I like how you conveniently informed us after most of us had eaten already and  we are [feeling full].

The phrase in brackets sounds unnatural to me. Would you suggest how to rephrase that better?

Comment: I don't think 'feeling full' sounds unnatural at all. But the sentence preceding it is a bit odd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a polite alternative to "No thanks, I'm full"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30734/is-there-a-polite-alternative-to-no-thanks-im-full)

Comment: your possible duplicate link is at very least superfluous and irrelevant to my question, though  I found that thread interesting as well, sir.

Comment: Assuming that the response is to someone who has revealed that food will will be provided shortly, I would change the sentence to: I like how you conveniently informed us after most of us had eaten and are already full. "are already feeling full" also sounds more natural in American English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possibilites:

- stuffed to bursting
- engorged
- fat and happy
- glutted
- well sated
- replete

Comment: full, stuffed, etc

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "...feeling full", "...are full" would feel more natural in your example.

If you don't like "full", other possibilities include "sated", "satisfied", and "stuffed".

Comment: +1 on "stuffed." Also, "stuffed to the gills."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make everyone look it up in their dictionaries, you could use "surfeited".

Answer (score 1):

I like the sound of "moderately incapacitated," or "somewhat incapacitated."

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling full (after eating), you are ***satiated***.

> I like how you conveniently informed us after most of us had eaten
> already and we are ***satiated***.

Collins:

> ***[satiated](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/satiated)***
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> filled or supplied beyond capacity or desire
> She finished the meal
> and sat back with a satiated sigh.
>
> He explains that he fools his mind to eat quickly, before it can tell
> his stomach it's satiated.
> *The Guardian (2015)*

Answer (score 0):

Note that I was warned *not* to say, “I’m stuffed,” in Britain, since it means something indecent there.  I think “I’m full” is safe on both sides of the Atlantic.

Answer (score -1):

There's always "suffonsified." Or the more formal "sufficiently [suffonsified](https://www.waywordradio.org/suffonsified/)."  Me, I'd go with "and we are already full" or "once we are so full we can't eat anymore" to really drive the point home.

Comment: I think someone made up that word as a joke by mashing together “satisfied” and “sufficient” or “suffused.´ The dictionaries that list it at all say it’s used “informally” in Canada. Probably by their girlfriends.

Comment: There certainly quite a bit of tongue-in-cheek implied. I'd thought of inserting a smiley or "grin" in my response but decided not to.